# Tableau: Filter results based on measure values

Tags: tableau-api

Tableau: I need to filter measure values for a particular month when multiple months are in display.

Example:
Rows = products (dimensions)
Columns = Months
I have filtered months on Column, displaying May June and July (entire year is in data set), and sale by products (dimensions) in the row.
Desired view: I only want the results of dimensions (products), when the "July" volume is greater than zero.  (Meaning, the sales volumes for some products can be more than one in May and June, but if zero in July, filter out). 
TY!

Answer (score 0):

Create a calculated field and make that a filter.

```
If [Month] = "July" and sum([Sales Volumes]) = 0 then "Hide"
else "Show"
end
```

Then filter to exclude the Hide values.